# How to display image from api in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have an API response which contains multiple images.I am using get service to get the text and images on the form.Text is coming but I am facing difficulties in retrieving images from API.Currenting I am providing value in output section but image is not displayed.

Key value from API for my image is:-***

> result_data_for_editing.media.mediaPath

---

My HTML where I want to retrieve my image is:-

```
<img type="file" id="files" multiple name="media" accept="image/*"/>
<output id="list" value="result_data_for_editing.media.mediaPath"></output>
```

and the corresponding javascript for creating thumbnails for that image is:-

```
$(document).on('click', '.browse', function () {
            var file = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.file');
            file.trigger('click');
        });
        $(document).on('change', '.file', function () {
            $(this).parent().find('.form-control').val($(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, ''));
        });
        //function to create thumbanil of images uploaded on client-side
        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            $("#list").html("");
            var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
            // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.

            for (var i = 0, validatedfiles, f; f = files[i], validatedfiles = files[i]; i++) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                var imagearray = [];
                imagearray = files[i];

                // Closure to capture the file information.
                reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                    return function (e) {
                        // Render thumbnail.
                        var span = document.createElement('span');

                        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumbs_image" src="', e.target.result, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');

                        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);

                    };
                })(imagearray);

                // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                reader.readAsDataURL(imagearray);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance